# Which is the correct implementation of the Preference Fragment for the Settings functionality?

Tags: android, preferencefragment

I would like to construct a settings page to appear as a full screen using PreferenceFragment. I will not be using the setting elsewhere.

Currently there are 2 ways to implement the preference fragment for creating the settings of an application,

**Method one**

1. Create a class and extend `PreferenceFragment` class.
2. Inflate the xml preference file.
3. Using the `FragmentManager` object replace the fragment in the layout.

**Method two**

1. Create an Activity with an XML layout.
2. In this Activity instantiate the fragment as in the above steps.
3. Call this activity when the preferences are to be displayed.

I wasn't able to find answers as how to properly implement the `PreferenceFragment`

[As per the PreferenceFragment docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html), they do not have information as to where to place the PreferenceFragment.

I tried method 1 but saw [this blog](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/example-of-using-preferencefragment.html) where it is implemented using method two. So I want to know which of the two is the proper implementation for the Settings functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

Whichever one fits your design.  The advantage of a `PreferenceFragment` is that the view doesn't have to fit the entire screen. You can include it in other `Activities`. You can embed it somewhere in your `Activity`. For example, you can use it as a [BottomSheet](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-sheets.html) or include it in a `ViewPager`.

Having a dedicated `Activity` can simplify development because the `Activity` only has one dedicated purpose. It generally will be a full-screen preferences screen which is most common.

Comment: Say if you are creating the "Settings" for an application so it should be implemented as a separate activity right ?

Comment: Yes.  I would implement that as an Activity.

Comment: Thanks this is the answer I was looking for and have edited my question. Please have a look and modify the answer if needed.

Comment: @WeirdNerd. I don't think there's a reason to change the answer.  A Settings page could still be on a ViewPager tab or in a bottom sheet depending on how the app is constructed. There really is no "right way". In your case, an Activity may be most suitable for now. Fullscreen pages are easier to implement as Activities than manipulating Fragments. Worry about  embedding it in the main activity when you *have* to. Then you know it's at least possible.